# Add multiple google schema ConfirmAction

Tags: gmail, schema.org, google-schemas

I am working on a project that would require some authorized users to 'Approve' or 'Reject' a request.

I would like these actions to be performed right from the user's inbox.

Is it possible to add more than one ConfirmAction that will be disabled once one of them is clicked. If yes, kindly provide a sample markup.

Answer (score 2):

Gmail only supports a single action. If you specify more than one action in your markup, only the first will be rendered.

Thanks for describing your use case, though, we plan to add new action types and this is a legit request.

Comment: Hi, is this answer still relevant?