# How to give users the ability to make request directly from the GMail?

Tags: gmail, schema.org, google-schemas, gmail-contextual-gadgets

Currently my service sends users an email with two links (action "A" and action "B"). Clicking on the link opens a new tab with action confirmation.
There was a desire to allow the user to select the action without opening a new tab, directly from the GMail.

To do this, I wanted to use the [Email Markup](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/), but it turned out that it only supports a single action. (I found it not in Email Markup docs, but on Stackoverflow, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18863016/1797618))

As an alternative, I would like to use [contextual gadgets](https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets), but the documentation says:

> There are two development and deployment models:
>
> - Develop a Gmail contextual gadget for use within a single    organization's Google Apps domains (an in-house application).
> - List the gadget for sale on the Google Apps Marketplace.

i.e. use gadgets for this purpose will not work.

**Is there some other opportunity to allow users to select the action directly in the GMail?**